# WatchService (Windows 7): when deleting a file, it fires both ENTRY_MODIFY and ENTRY_DELETE events?

Tags: java, watchservice

In working with the WatchService, I found that if I delete a file in the directory being watched, it fires an `ENTRY_MODIFY` followed by an `ENTRY_DELETE` event.

I realize that technically, a file may be modified before deleted, but is it really the expected behavior that deleting a file will trigger ENTRY_MODIFY  (which presumably no one cares about)?

To handle this, I had to add a condition to check before firing passing along the ENTRY_MODIFY event:

```
            if (eventKind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                listener.fileCreated(file);
            } else if (eventKind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                if (Files.exists(fullPath, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                    listener.fileChanged(file);
                }
            } else if (eventKind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                listener.fileDeleted(file);
            }
```

Is this there a better way to handle this issue (feature)?

Comment: I believe this is expected, and the single line of code you are using to handle this behaviour seems like a simple solution to me.

Comment: @colti: I didn't have a chance to test on Linux yet.  Is there any difference in behavior between Windows and Linux here?

Comment: It is possible but I don't know for sure. The Linux implementation uses inotify, if you would like to read up on that: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: On my machine Files.exists() is returning true after the ENTRY_MODIFY event is received, unless waiting for around 10ms, which makes this incredibly unreliable. Is there no better way?

Comment: I'm running under Windows 7 and find the WatchService's behavior anything but reliable when deleting. Sometimes I get an ENTRY_MODIFIED and an ENTRY_DELETE when I delete a file. Other times I get just a single ENTRY_MODIFIED. And as @Fulluphigh mentioned checking to see if the file exists is unreliable as well. I'm running with Java 1.8 vm, though compiled for 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

I can only confirm the issue. From the comments and from my own observations, the `ENTRY_MODIFY` event is fired just before the file is deleted and you have to deal with it.

Suppose we have two threads. One is doing `Files.delete()`, the other is watching the directory and trying to read modified files. Any of the following can happen:

1. `Files.delete()` just manages to modify and delete the file, before the event is picked up by the watching thread. Then the technique to check the file existence after `ENTRY_MODIFY` works.
2. the `Files.delete()` call can fail (return `false`), as the file is already opened by the watching thread.

The only resolution seems to be to ignore all `IOExceptions` in the watching thread and to retry the `Files.delete()` call few times.

I only tried to delete the files from the same JVM with `Files.delete()`. I did not try to delete from other process on the system. Problem reproduces on Windows 7~10 with NTFS, probably not on other OSes.

I encourage others to edit this answer and add their observations.